# Zend framework 1: form validation of two related fields

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework

My ZF1-form has fieldland and fieldnumber which are related to each other and i need to check that either both or none are filled. How to do this validation? In ZF1 forms have no method setValidatorGroup. So is there an alternative?

The form is defined in a xml, so fielddefinition looks like:

```
    <klant_mobiel_land>
        <type>text</type>
        <options>
            <label>Mobiel landcode, abonneenummer:</label>
            <maxlength>5</maxlength>
            <size>5</size>
            <validators>
                <telefoonnummerlandcodecinco>
                   <validator>TelefoonnummerLandcodeCinco</validator>
                </telefoonnummerlandcodecinco>
            </validators>
        </options>
    </klant_mobiel_land>
    <klant_mobiel_nummer>
        <type>text</type>
        <options>
            <maxlength>10</maxlength>
            <size>15</size>
        </options>
    </klant_mobiel_nummer>
```

I expect to need a validationgroup, first of all, is that on option? And second, how should that be defined in xml? Something like this perhaps:

```
  <validationgroups>
        <mobilephone_group>
            <elements>
                <klant_mobiel_nr>klant_mobiel_nummer</klant_mobiel_nr>
                <klant_mobiel_land>klant_mobiel_land</klant_mobiel_land>
            </elements>
            <validators>
                <neitherorbothfields>
                    <validator>neitherorbothfields</validator>
                </neitherorbothfields>
            </validators>
        </mobilephone_group>
    </validationgroups>
```

And the validator itself, how should it get the two values passed to it? Something like this perhaps:

```
class Zend_Validate_NeitherOrBothFields extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
     public function isValid($value, $context = null)
    {
        if (mytestToSeeIfNeitherOrBothAreFilled) {
            $this->_error('Only one of the two fields has been filled, fill either none or both', $value);
            return false;
        };
        return true;
    }
```

Best regards, Tim van Steenbergen, tieka.nl

Comment: But why? Show one error for one field and other error for other field. This is expected behaviour of applications.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the validator uses the optional `$context` var, precisely as you have indicated above. But you will attach the validator to a single field (so any validation failures will also be attached to that field).

The standard example is a registration form that solicits a `password` value and a `confirm_password` value. The validator could be attached to the `password` field and the validator's `isValid($value, $context = null)` method would compare `$value` to `$context['confirm_password']`. A failure would then set an error on the `password` field which would then be referenced in the view-script or the form-decorators.

Answer (score 0):

You can have you custom validator, and use the 2nd parameter available to isValid to have other post fields something like following:

```
class Zend_Validate_NeitherOrBothFields  extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    public function isValid($value, $context = NULL) {
       // in $context you will have all data from post which you can use to validate and do the stuffs you want and the end you can set the error message and return true/false
        if ($context['password'] !== $context['confirm_password']) {
            $this->_error('some message');
            return false; 
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then in your Zend Form just bind this validator to one of your field (say just to password)